# What happens to Harry's Firebolt and trunk after they fell from the flying motorcycle?

Tags: harry-potter

During the Battle of the Seven Potters (HP7), Harry loses his Firebolt and his trunk as they both fell from the flying motorcycle. He can see those items falling to the ground, but manages to keep Hedwig and his backpack in the side-car.

My question is: What happened to his stuff after it fell? I mean, the battle is supposed to take place in mid-air, perhaps over a large city, so his stuff may have fallen onto a road, into a garden, into a field, or at least somewhere Muggles could come. Did he get it back after the battle?

Comment: If it's not explicitly mentioned in the book I'm not sure there's any way to know for sure. It's likely the Ministry would have done some cleaning up to avoid Muggles coming across anything they shouldn't have done though, so they may have just taken it away.

Comment: Alright :) Then I suppose the Ministry went quite happy to get a Firebolt. Maybe they sell it in an auction. Oh, and thanks to @Slytherincess for editing my post that was full of typos and gramatical errors. I won't make French people image better like this...

Comment: Accio Firebolt? Accio trunk?

Comment: Or even seized by stray DE's hoping for something to use against Harry & Co.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no specific indication what happened to the Firebolt after it fell from the sidecar of Hargid's motorcycle.

Ultimately there are only three options, none of which are explicitly confirmed or denied in the text;

- **The firebolt was destroyed in the fall.**

This seems pretty unlikely. The brooms are described as being well made and tightly bound. There's no particular reason to assume that it would break on impact even if dropped from height.

- **The broom survived and was collected by the Ministry of Magic (or Harry) after the battle of Hogwarts.**

This is *quite* plausible. The Ministry are tasked with enforcing the Statute of Secrecy which would certainly include collecting magical artefacts.

- **The broom came into the possession of a muggle who has no idea that it's magical.**

This is the most likely option. Given the speed at which they were travelling (and the cloud cover and the height) Harry is highly unlikely to know where the broom landed which would hamper his ability to find it.

It's clear from HP1 that while a broom may be a magical item, without a competent wizard to command it, it'll just sit on the floor doing nothing so **the most likely outcome therefore is that a muggle found it and that it's sat in a cupboard somewhere**.

Comment: I would assume that there would be anti break enchantments on the brooms. There's a couple of incidents in the books and movies where people plow into the dirt at speed playing Quidditch, they break the brooms don't. :)

Comment: @JohnP - Even a normal broom is pretty hard to break by dropping; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5JjSZJ0hlE ;-)

Comment: I was supporting your argument that it was unlikely to be destroyed in the fall, not knocking it.

Comment: And now my mind is brewing with the plot of a random muggle who uses the quite expensive Firebolt to sweep dust from out of corners...and one day, their child finds it, tries to fly on it, and discovers in the most fun way ever that they're a wizard/witch.

Comment: @Zibbobz - It certainly lends itself very well to all sorts of fanfics about muggles with latent powers.

Comment: @Zibbobz - To be followed by said muggle figuring out airbrakes/bags :p

Comment: @JohnP - TO be followed by said muggle shrieking like a little girl and falling to their grisly death.

Comment: @Richard - Very true. Hopefully wearing a GoPro so we can get the footage on one of the video "everyone finds shots to the nuts funny" kind of tv shows.

Comment: @JohnP - Or landing on a fence "Ow, My Balls!" style; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAg1r6zw7Bg

Comment: Doesn't look like the sort of thing even a muggle would mistake for such a mundane artifact as a common household broom, with the curved handle, footrests (even if not understood to be such), and juxtaposition of the finely crafted metal with rustic bristles which look more like tree twigs than straw. If found by a muggle, it would definitely need to be recovered by the MoM, along with liberal use of "obliviate".

Answer (score 6):

To be clear Harry didn't have his trunk with him during the battle of the 7 potters, he had a backpack/rucksack, his broom, and Hedwig. As Valorium points out we really don't know what happens to Harry's FireBolt, but Harry catches his rucksack.

> The broomstick spun to earth, but he just managed to seize the
>   strap of his rucksack and the top of the cage as the motorbike
>   swung the right way up again.

Harry previously unpacked his trunk, and filled this rucksack with all of his important things.

I think its important to note a giant trunk did not fall through the sky's and kill any more poor muggles.

Answer (score 1):

With the Accio spell Harry could retrieve the broom at any if he knew the general flight path.

He did summon it from the castle during the Tri-Wizard Tournament. So we know Accio can work if Harry is within a plausible distance. It wouldn't be that hard; just follow the flight path and keep saying Accio until you get the broom back...